# Apply conditional groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two month value columns as 'month1' and 'month2'. If the value in 'month1' column is not 'NA', then sum the corresponding 'amount' values as per 'month1' column. If the value in 'month1' column is 'NA', then sum the corresponding 'amount' values of 'month2' column.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'month1': [1,2,'NA', 1, 4, 'NA', 'NA'],
          'month2': ['NA',5,1, 2, 'NA', 1, 3],
          'amount': [10,20,40, 50, 60, 70, 100]})
```

The input and output dataframes are as follows:

Input dataframe

```
   month1  month2  amount
0     1.0     NaN      10
1     2.0     5.0      20
2     NaN     1.0      40
3     1.0     2.0      50
4     4.0     NaN      60
5     NaN     1.0      70
6     NaN     3.0     100
```

Output dataframe

[image]

Comment: Please edit your pictures to code otherwise you might get downvoted.

Comment: What happens when both values are non-NA?

Comment: If both are non-NA, sum will be according to 'month1' column.

Comment: @CeliusStingher A newbie to positing questions on Stack. Still learning.

Answer (score 1):

since your `NA` values is string, you can simply `groupby` on the two columns:

```
# ignore month2 if month1 is NA
df.loc[df.month1.ne('NA'), 'month2'] = 'NA'

# groupby and sum
df.groupby(['month1','month2']).amount.transform('sum')
```

if you don't want to alter your data, you can do

```
s = np.where(df.month1.ne('NA'), 'NA', df['month2'])

df.groupby(['month1', s]).amount.transform('sum')
```

Output:

```
0     60
1     20
2    110
3     60
4     60
5    110
6    100
Name: amount, dtype: int64
```

Comment: 2nd solution is cleaner IMO ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
c=df.month1.eq('NA')
np.select([c,~c],[df.groupby('month2')['amount'].transform('sum')
     ,df.groupby('month1')['amount'].transform('sum')],default='NA') #assign to new column
```

---

```
array(['60', '20', '110', '60', '60', '110', '100'], dtype='<U21')
```

Comment: why does it fail without the `transform` clause?

Comment: Transforms broadcasts values back to their respectivos rows. If you just `.sum()`, they'll be aggregated, so the `condList` and `choiceList` would have different lengths

Comment: yeah, that's exactly the error I had until I noticed this answer using transform, still lots to learn, thank you sirs/madames :)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: as @rafael pointed out, your data may be mixing of numbers and strings, so converting them all to numeric before processing is needed.

A simple way is `groupby` and `transform` month1 and month2 separately and fillna result of month1 by month2

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
m1 = df.groupby('month1').amount.transform('sum')
m2 = df.groupby('month2').amount.transform('sum')

m1.fillna(m2)

Out[406]:
0    60.0
1    20.0
2    110.0
3    60.0
4    60.0
5    110.0
6    100.0
Name: amount, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Looks good. Just an addendum that OP might need `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')` before running this

Comment: @rafaelc: hah, you're right. I overlooked that OP provided codes for sample data. I just copied the sample data table and use `read_clipboard`, so I didn't notice that data may be strings. Thanks for pointing it out.